# Having Windows 7 and want to install a new Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, windows-7, format

I have Windows 7 in my laptop and I want to start installing Ubuntu 13.04. Do I have to format all my partitions in Windows before I can start installing Ubuntu? If not, then it means I'll be installing Ubuntu on my 'primary partition' which is C:. What about the other partitions I have in Windows 7. I have these three partitions in my Windows. My Question is if I install Ubuntu into one of these partitions and will I lose those two partitions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able, setup Ubuntu on a separate drive.

Windows is very aggressive at corrupting competitive systems.  I have setup separate drives for Linux and Windows so that Windows never gets to access that drive.

Also always keep your data on an external (USB) drive.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a lot! I appreciate your help. I'll use another drive like External Hard-disk to install Ubuntu in. I'll try with 12.10 as you suggested. thanks!